# SQL запрос с курсором. Почему переменная записывается только раз?

Tags: sql, запрос

Пытаюсь вывести все id с поля HostelCode но возникает несколько проблем:

```
1) Как сохранять сообщения из print чтобы они не стирались при каждом новом выводе
2) Почему - то запрос срабатывает только один раз (выводит последний HostelCode) а при повторном запуске перестает вообще что-то выводить
```

Сам запрос:

```
Declare @HostelId int;

Declare @Hostels Cursor;

SET @Hostels  = cursor for select Hostel.HostelCode
From  Hostel

Open @Hostels 
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Fetch next from @Hostels into @HostelId
Begin 
    Print @HostelId
End
Close @Hostels
```

Пример ошибочной работы:

Вместо `Declare @HostelId int;` пишу `Declare @HostelId int=0`
и при первом запуске запроса, выведет то что нужно, после следующих запусков будет выводить 0

Comment: 1) Укажите точно Вашу DBMS. 2) У Вас не закрыт While, в таком состоянии, вероятно, он воспринимается как состоящий из одного оператора Fetch, тогда он выгребет все записи из курсора, и только потом перейдёт к следующему Begin-End. Потому и выведет только последний.

Comment: это очень похоже на sql server. @Ashen One, вы задавали вчера вопросы по Mysql, вам код курсора нужен для MySQL или для Sql Server-а?